# Find average hours for each id in hive

Tags: sql, datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have data set to look like this:-

```
 Id      working_hour
1005    2019-10-23 08:35:00
1006    2019-10-23 00:54:59
1007    2019-10-23 00:24:57
1008    2019-10-23 06:40:00
1009    2019-10-23 03:50:00
1010    2019-10-23 03:25:01
1005    2019-10-24 05:25:00
1006    2019-10-24 01:39:59
1007    2019-10-24 02:30:00
1008    2019-10-24 09:45:01
1010    2019-10-24 07:00:00
```

These are two days data set(23/10/2019 and 24/10/2019). I want ro find the avg working hours(in hours or min) for each Id.

Like:-

```
 Id    in_hours  in_mins
1005      7       420     # (08:35+3:35)/2 = 7 hours
1006    1.29    77.4835   # (00:54:59+01:39:59)/2 = 1.29 hours
```

Comment: Please explain how the results are derived from the sample data.  It is not clear.

Comment: Please check it again. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it as simple as possible. For me, it's working properly.

```
SELECT user_name, from_unixtime(CAST(AVG(unix_timestamp(substr(working_hours,12),"HH:mm:ss"))as bigint),"HH:mm:ss") as avg_hours FROM workinglogs1 GROUP BY user_name ORDER BY avg_hours'
```

Here, I'm teking only HH:mm:ss from working hours using substr(working_hours,12), then find unix_time stamp for working hours. After that i'm taking avg and convert into timestamp using from_unixtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use windowing functions. lead and lag specifically will help this use case.  I did not execute this sql but the concept is there.

```
Select (id, working_ho, nextwH)
from (
Select id, working_hour, lead(working_hour) over partition_by id order_by working hour) nextWH
from tableA)
```

This will result in data that looks like this.
id  |working_hour       | nextWH

1005|2019-10-23 08:35:00|2019-10-24 05:25:00

1005|2019-10-24 05:25:00|null

Then filter out the records where nextWH is null and use date time functions to calculate the difference between working_hour and nextWH to your liking.

here is a link to windowing functions documentation.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-LEADusingdefault1rowleadandnotspecifyingdefaultvalue

Comment: No, It's not working. I want each id avg working hours. @betico

Comment: Does working_hour column represent the start, end, or duration of an id?

Comment: yes, after subtracting start time with the end time find working_hour(or duration). @betico

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach

your data with working_hour as timestamp

```
+------------------+----------------------------+--+
| working_hour.id  | working_hour.working_hour  |
+------------------+----------------------------+--+
| 1005             | 2019-10-23 08:35:00.0      |
| 1006             | 2019-10-23 00:54:59.0      |
| 1007             | 2019-10-23 00:24:57.0      |
| 1008             | 2019-10-23 06:40:00.0      |
| 1009             | 2019-10-23 03:50:00.0      |
| 1010             | 2019-10-23 03:25:01.0      |
| 1005             | 2019-10-24 05:25:00.0      |
| 1006             | 2019-10-24 01:39:59.0      |
| 1007             | 2019-10-24 02:30:00.0      |
| 1008             | 2019-10-24 09:45:01.0      |
| 1009             | 2019-10-24 02:10:00.0      |
| 1010             | 2019-10-24 07:00:00.0      |
+------------------+----------------------------+--+
```

with windowing function lead and converting timestamp in seconds, calculate the difference between the two timestamp in seconds and convert seconds in minutes and hours.

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT id, working_hour, LEAD(working_hour) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY working_hour) AS nextDay
FROM working_hour
) SELECT id, working_hour, nextDay, 
         ROUND((unix_timestamp(nextDay) - unix_timestamp(working_hour)) / 2, 2) AS in_secs, --AVG in seconds
         ROUND((unix_timestamp(nextDay) - unix_timestamp(working_hour)) / 60 / 2,2) AS in_mins, --AVG in minutes
         ROUND((unix_timestamp(nextDay) - unix_timestamp(working_hour)) / 60 / 60 / 2,2) AS in_hours --AVG in hours
FROM t
WHERE nextDay IS NOT NULL;
```

and output

```
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--+
|  id   |      working_hour      |        nextday         | in_secs  | in_mins  | in_hours  |
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--+
| 1005  | 2019-10-23 08:35:00.0  | 2019-10-24 05:25:00.0  | 37500.0  | 625.0    | 10.42     |
| 1006  | 2019-10-23 00:54:59.0  | 2019-10-24 01:39:59.0  | 44550.0  | 742.5    | 12.38     |
| 1007  | 2019-10-23 00:24:57.0  | 2019-10-24 02:30:00.0  | 46951.5  | 782.53   | 13.04     |
| 1008  | 2019-10-23 06:40:00.0  | 2019-10-24 09:45:01.0  | 48750.5  | 812.51   | 13.54     |
| 1009  | 2019-10-23 03:50:00.0  | 2019-10-24 02:10:00.0  | 40200.0  | 670.0    | 11.17     |
| 1010  | 2019-10-23 03:25:01.0  | 2019-10-24 07:00:00.0  | 49649.5  | 827.49   | 13.79     |
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+----------+----------+-----------+--+
```

You could follow this approach too

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT id, working_hour, LEAD(working_hour) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY working_hour) AS nextDay
FROM working_hour
) SELECT id, working_hour, nextDay, 
          ROUND( ((hour(nextDay) * 60 + minute(nextDay) + hour(working_hour) * 60 + minute(working_hour)) / 60 / 2),2) AS in_hours,
          ROUND( ((hour(nextDay) * 60 + minute(nextDay) + hour(working_hour) * 60 + minute(working_hour)) / 2),2) AS in_mins
FROM t
WHERE nextDay IS NOT NULL;
```

output

```
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--+
|  id   |      working_hour      |        nextday         | in_hours  | in_mins  |
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--+
| 1005  | 2019-10-23 08:35:00.0  | 2019-10-24 05:25:00.0  | 7.0       | 420.0    |
| 1006  | 2019-10-23 00:54:59.0  | 2019-10-24 01:39:59.0  | 1.28      | 76.5     |
| 1007  | 2019-10-23 00:24:57.0  | 2019-10-24 02:30:00.0  | 1.45      | 87.0     |
| 1008  | 2019-10-23 06:40:00.0  | 2019-10-24 09:45:01.0  | 8.21      | 492.5    |
| 1009  | 2019-10-23 03:50:00.0  | 2019-10-24 02:10:00.0  | 3.0       | 180.0    |
| 1010  | 2019-10-23 03:25:01.0  | 2019-10-24 07:00:00.0  | 5.21      | 312.5    |
+-------+------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--+
```

I hope this help.

Comment: that query does not work because I want avg of total working_hour. your output for id 1005 in hours 10.42 but as you see my output is 7.0 because (8:35+5:25)/2 = 7.0 not 10.42. @Chema

Comment: I am using Timestamp you provided, I think is 8:35 in the morning to 24:00 --> 16 hours plus  5 --> 21 hours / 2 --> 10.xx more or less. I think it is right.

Comment: I got the timestamp in seconds as you can see, and the difference are passed from seconds to minutes and hours.

Comment: And timestamp is in 24 hours format because in other way it would have to point out a.m. or p.m.

Comment: No, here working hours are total work on that day. Means here is 1005 is working 8 hours and 35 mins on 23/10/2019. Not as 24:00 - 8:35. Please check my question properly @Chema

Comment: Ok, but tell me how do you calculate id 1006? I would like to know. And 1.29 hours is not 77.485 minutes.

Comment: Same as 1005, like for 1006 - (00:54:59 + 1:39:59)/2 = (2.58278 hours)/2 = 1.29139 hours. @Chema

Comment: And id 1005 would have to be (13 * 60) + 55 / 2 == 417.5 and 6.775 hours

Comment: why 55? 35 mins + 25 min = 60 min not 55 min and 8 hour + 5 hours = 13 hours. after add both 13 hours + 60 min = 14 hours. Then I want average 14/2 = 7 hours. Hope you got it !

Comment: I think so, it is easy to change, I will put another version in my answer, but I want to keep the previous version too.

Comment: here why are you add 1009 id on 24/10/2019? In my table, it's not present. Do you have any other method to solve this problem because for the large table it takes more time to run? @Chema

Comment: It was for testing purpose. You can optimize your queries by bucketing or partitioning your tables or creating stage tables.